# Error malloc on string from argv

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, argv, strlen, argc

I'm using a string received from the arg to return another string with characters shuffled.

```
int size = strlen(argv[4]);
char* res = malloc(size+1);
```

Then res is filled with the characters of argv[4], but when I type 'test' in the console, it returns 'Test?' (when I'm not shuffling the letters but just copying the string, character by character).

Why is that ?

If I put size+100 instead, it works, but I don't get why.

Comment: How are you copying the string ? Are you including the `\0` ?

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to include the \0, it is corrected now, but that was not the problem. Thanks !

Comment: @Sheeft Check the comments and edit to your accepted answer - it was wrong, but it may be masking your actual problem.

Comment: @NigelHarper The exact same way +100 was originally masking the problem.

Comment: _when I type 'test' in the console .... _ Could you show all arguments supplied to the program? You play with 4-th = argv[4]. Is argv[1], argv[2],  argv[3] ok?

Answer (score -2):

That is because you did not take into account what the size of char is. This should do the trick:

```
char* res = (char*)malloc((size+1)*sizeof(char))
```

Comment: Oh yeah thanks, I used sizeof(char) instead of sizeof(char*)… I indeed did the trick !

Comment: Why would you multiply by `sizeof(char *)` ? This is most definitely not the right answer.

Comment: Since sizeof(char) is always 1 your edited answer is exactly equivalent to what the OP had, so it's not an answer.

Comment: Aww right, but now I don't get why it doesn't work the way it is…

Comment: I don't get how, but it seems the problem is corrected (I returned to the way it was) now. It's weird !

Thank you for your answers.